# Sub string by character from Table Type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to substring from list of table type.

Code is below

```
 @Description AS dbo.ListStringTableType
```

And @Description have like list of data below

```
Test+Again
Today+Tomorrow
```

And looking to sub string by char '+'

```
Col1        Col2
-----       -----
Test        Again
Today       Tomorrow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the substring using charindex as below.

```
declare @var varchar(20)='Test+Again'

select substring(@var,1,CHARINDEX('+',@var)-1) as col1
,substring(@var,CHARINDEX('+',@var)+1,len(@var)) as col2
```

The @var variable should be the column in your case.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2016 has the `split()` function.  But, you can instead just do:

```
select v.col1, v.col2
from t outer apply
     (values (left(col, charindex('+', col) - 1),
              stuff(col, 1, charindex('+', col), '')
             )
     ) v(col1, col2);
```

Comment: this query returning like col1 as Test+A and col2 as Again

Answer (score 0):

```
Select left(description,charindex('+', description)-1) as col1, 
right(description,len(description)-charindex('+', description)) as col2
```

CharIndex will help to find the 1st position of the string we provide, For col1 we require string before string '+', so we are using the 'left' function here.
'left' will fetch the number of letters from the start to the length mentioned(extracted via charindex function, will return the position of the exact string in the given input).
Similarly, for col2 we require string after string '+', so we are using the 'right' function here.
'right' will fetch the number of letters from the last to the length mentioned(total length of the string - length extracted via charindex function).
For More Info about, Right, Left Function, please use below link.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

Comment: Try to explain your answer with some relevant comments. Dumping the code doesn't always help. :)

Comment: Will do, Sure Thanks